# How to enable Java EE in Apache NetBeans 11

Tags: java, netbeans

I have installed Apache NetBeans 11 and JDK 8. I have also downloaded Java EE 8 and extracted it to C:/ folder. I opened Apache NetBeans 11 and tried to follow the instructions in the previous questions for enabling Java EE in Apache NetBeans 10. All plugins have been enabled, however the option for Java EE base is missing.

[image: the option for Java EE base is missing]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Are there any steps I have missed?

Comment: If you installed Netbeans 11, "i have opened apache netbeans 11 ", why are you trying to enable it within Netbeans 10?

Comment: it was a mistake i meant Netbeans 11